# How to perform the optimization when gradient is a matrix $\mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-calculus

I am trying to optimize this cost function by using Gauss-Newton method.
$$f = \sum_{i = 1}^n Tr{(Z^TZ)}$$
where $Z$ is a $4\times4$ matrix and it is a function of real vector $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{R}^5$. And because I am using Gauss-Newton approach, I define $g \in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to be $\sqrt{Tr(Z^T_iZ_i)} = \sqrt{p_i}$, where $i = 1,2,...,n$

This is my attempt to find the gradient and its Hessian $H$. Gradient of the cost function is $2J^Tg$ and Hessian is $2(J^TJ + \sum(g_iH_i))$, where $J$ is Jacobian matrix.

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial\epsilon}|_{\epsilon = 0} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial\epsilon}|_{\epsilon = 0}$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial\epsilon}|_{\epsilon = 0} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{p_i}}Z(\epsilon\vec{a})\frac{\partial Z(\epsilon\vec{a})}{\partial\epsilon}|_{\epsilon = 0}$$

Apparently, the expression above is going to be $4\times4$ matrix. How to proceed find the gradient of the cost function because we cannot multiply $J$ and $g$ right away? I have tried with Hessian matrix and it is even worse. I am not sure whether I am on the right path or not so I did not show my attempt on Hessian here.

Comment: You need the [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274)!

Comment: Are you aware that $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z^TZ)$ is simply $\sum_{i,j} Z_{ij}^2$? Yes, the sum of the squares of the elements of $Z$. That should make the calculus rather simple.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at the cookbook. According to your comment, my $g_i$ will be $\mathbb{R}^{16}$, and Jacobian will be of dimension $5\times16$, correct?

Comment: I believe so but I am rusty on my Gauss Newton. I see no reason not to convert Z to a 16-element vector though!

Comment: Come to think of it, my $g_i$ will still be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If we change from the cost function into sum of square, the cost will be $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j,k}Z_{jk}^2$ and the problem will still be the same.

Comment: Why use Gauss-Newton? Why not use straight up Newton minimization on $f$?

Comment: Instead of Gauss-Newton, consider methods which don't require a Hessian, like Conjugate Gradient or L-BFGS.

Answer (score 0):

Your [latest formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157423/how-to-determine-the-gradient-of-this-cost) of the cost function can be greatly simplified 
$$ \eqalign {
 f &= \sum_k {\rm tr}\bigg((A_kX)^T(A_kX)\bigg) \cr
   &= \sum_k (A_k^TA_k):(XX^T) \cr
   &= M:(XX^T) \cr
} $$
by summing the $A_k$ once and for all, and removing them from the problem. I also replaced the trace function with a Frobenius product for algebraic convenience.

Next, instead of jumping immediately to the chain rule, let's find the differential of $f$.
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= M:d(XX^T) \cr
    &= M:(dXX^T + XdX^T) \cr
    &= (M+M^T):dXX^T \cr
    &= (M+M^T)X:dX \cr
    &= 2\,MX:dX \cr
} $$
You haven't provided enough information about $X=X(a)$ for me to evaluate the derivative, but it will look like this
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial a^T} &= 2\,MX : \bigg(\frac {\partial X} {\partial a^T}\bigg) \cr
  &= 2\,{\rm vec}(MX)^T\,\,\frac {\partial {\rm vec}(X)} {\partial a^T} \cr
} $$